# Mapping Network drive on Raspberry pi 3 Not Working

Tags: linux, samba

I'm trying to figure out where I'm mistaken. I have Pi 3 that runs the following:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
```

on the other host, I have windows 10 installed. I want to map a network drive from the pi to my win 10, but for some reason, I can't. Your help is much appreciated. I've done the following:

Install Samba
Changed the `samba.conf` to be writeable and browseable
Service is up and running including all the daemons inside.
I have pinged my Pi successfully.

All the relevant ports are opened. 445/139 (is that enough?)
DNS client service is running on my Windows PC and relevant dependencies.
Network sharing is enabled in windows.
the error message that I got when trying to \ip-address\shared folder is the regular windows pop-up error saying that it "couldn't find the path."

I also tried to search the samba logs, and I found a folder with my windows 10 PC, but it was empty.

here is my conf file

```
Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
#
#
# This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
# smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
# here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which 
# are not shown in this example
#
# Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
# commented-out examples in this file.
#  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
#    differs from the default Samba behaviour
#  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
#    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
#    enough to be mentioned here
#
# NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
# "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic 
# errors. 

#======================= Global Settings =======================

[global]

## Browsing/Identification ###

# Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
   workgroup = WORKGROUP

# Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
# WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
#   wins support = no

# WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
# Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
;   wins server = w.x.y.z

# This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.
   dns proxy = no

#### Networking ####

# The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
# This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
# interface names are normally preferred
;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

# Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
# 'interfaces' option above to use this.
# It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
# not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
# option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
;   bind interfaces only = yes



#### Debugging/Accounting ####

# This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
# that connects
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m

# Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).
   max log size = 1000

# If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
# parameter to 'yes'.
#   syslog only = no

# We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
# should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
# through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.
   syslog = 0

# Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d


####### Authentication #######
security = user
# Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
# values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
# domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
# directory domain controller". 
#
# Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
# Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
# running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
# new domain.
   server role = standalone server

# If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
# password database type you are using.  
   passdb backend = tdbsam

   obey pam restrictions = yes

# This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
# password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
# passdb is changed.
   unix password sync = yes

# For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
# parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
# sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .

# This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
# when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
# 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.
   pam password change = yes

# This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
# to anonymous connections
   map to guest = bad user

########## Domains ###########

#
# The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
# classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
# or 'domain logons' is set 
#

# It specifies the location of the user's
# profile directory from the client point of view) The following
# required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
# below)
;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
# Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
# (this is Samba's default)
#   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
# point of view)
;   logon drive = H:
#   logon home = \\%N\%U

# The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
# It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
# in the [netlogon] share
# NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
;   logon script = logon.cmd

# This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
# password; please adapt to your needs
; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

# This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the 
# SAMR RPC pipe.  
# The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

# This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
# RPC pipe.  
; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

############ Misc ############

# Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
# on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
# of the machine that is connecting
;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

# Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
# for something else.)
;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
;   template shell = /bin/bash

# Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
# with the net usershare command.

# Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
;   usershare max shares = 100

# Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
# public shares, not just authenticated ones
   usershare allow guests = yes

#======================= Share Definitions =======================

[homes]
   comment = Home Directories
   browseable = yes

# By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
# next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
   read only = no

# File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
   create mask = 0700

# Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
# create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
   directory mask = 0700

# By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
# with access to the samba server.
# The following parameter makes sure that only "username" can connect
# to \\server\username
# This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
   valid users = %S

# Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
;[netlogon]
;   comment = Network Logon Service
;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
;   guest ok = yes
;   read only = yes

# Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
# users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
# (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
# The path below should be writable by all users so that their
# profile directory may be created the first time they log on
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   guest ok = no
;   browseable = no
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
# Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
# You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
# admin users are members of.
# Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
# to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
;   write list = root, @lpadmin

[pi]
path=/home/pi
read only = no
writeable = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0755
directory mask = 0755
```

also nmbd logs

```
[2022/02/22 15:22:38.768222,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2022/02/22 15:23:01.807857,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****
  
  Samba name server HOMEASSISTANT is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 10.100.102.36
  
  *****
[2022/02/22 15:46:23.052054,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:58(terminate)
  Got SIGTERM: going down...
[2022/02/22 15:46:39.797278,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:135(daemon_status)
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' : No local IPv4 non-loopback interfaces available, waiting for interface ...NOTE: NetBIOS name resolution is not supported for Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6).
[2022/02/22 15:46:44.803103,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2022/02/22 15:47:51.987698,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****
  
  Samba name server HOMEASSISTANT is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 10.100.102.36
  
  *****
[2022/02/22 15:56:10.549188,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:58(terminate)
  Got SIGTERM: going down...
[2022/02/22 15:56:29.783882,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2022/02/22 15:57:38.407657,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****
  
  Samba name server HOMEASSISTANT is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 10.100.102.36
  
  *****
[2022/02/24 08:46:48.242014,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd.c:58(terminate)
  Got SIGTERM: going down...
[2022/02/24 08:46:58.581344,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:135(daemon_status)
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' : No local IPv4 non-loopback interfaces available, waiting for interface ...NOTE: NetBIOS name resolution is not supported for Internet Protocol Version 6 (IPv6).
[2022/02/24 08:47:08.588740,  0] ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)
  STATUS=daemon 'nmbd' finished starting up and ready to serve connections
[2022/02/24 08:48:14.188377,  0] ../source3/nmbd/nmbd_become_lmb.c:397(become_local_master_stage2)
  *****
  
  Samba name server HOMEASSISTANT is now a local master browser for workgroup WORKGROUP on subnet 10.100.102.36
  
  *****
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Would you mind sharing the `samba.conf` and relevant parts from the logs, as well as add if you've ran `smbpasswd`?

Comment: @mashuptwice, posted in the question.

Comment: Ok, you've added the config. Would you mind sharing the relevant parts from the logs, as well as add if you've ran smbpasswd after installation?

Comment: posted in the question (nmbd logs) and no, I didn't ran smbpasswd. should I?

Comment: Definitely yes. as suggested [here](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-samba/) and[here](https://jamesdixon.dev/posts/setting-up-smb-on-a-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: well still not working. the smbpasswd ts just crating access with some user.i don't even get the session connectivity. it's like I'm using a different network which I not. my PC and the pi are in the same network

Comment: found the issue. from some reason, my PC block the connection. all the settings from the beginning were fine. i switched to another Laptop and everything goes well. Thanks for the help